# SONIA Reference Data Calculation / OIS Data

Tags: data, swaps, ois, rfr

I am reading material reference rates calculation for SONIA by refinitiv. It says the data is calculated based on OIS Rates between 10:50AM and 11:00 AM.

https://www.refinitiv.com/content/dam/marketing/en_us/documents/methodology/refinitiv-term-sonia-benchmark-statement.pdf

I have following questions:

1. Why do they choose that particular time window for calculation of reference rate?
2. Where can I get OIS spread data to cross check the data from refinitiv?

This is only for educational purpose.

Regards,

Comment: because Benchmarks always use a window, it is published at 11:50 (so centering it around 11 is the most natural choice).  The 4pm FX fix is [similar](https://www.refinitiv.com/content/dam/marketing/en_us/documents/methodology/rbsl-benchmark-statement-wm-refinitiv-methodology.pdf). Choice of window size depends on liquidity.  Why replicate? Benchmarks are inherently difficult to replicate (otherwise they would be easy to manipulate which makes it useless to use as a Benchmark).

Comment: @AKdemy : Thanks.  I am interested in seeing OIS rates for SOFR. Is there any free data source available online. I checked ICE but couldn't retrieve the data.